# Mongoose pre-save hook not encrypting password on findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm running mongoose on a node application. I've got a collection of User documents, pretty straightforward. I have .pre middleware that should be encrypting passwords with bcrypt when it's a new record or when the password is being updated. However, though it works fine with new User documents, it is not encrypting when doing findOneAndUpdate.

I do realize that this has been asked and ostensibly answered, but none of the solutions I've found here or elsewhere have worked.

Here is the schema:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = new Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
```

...and here is my middleware:

```
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }

  try {
    // Hash the password synchronously
    const saltRounds = 10;
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, saltRounds);

    // Override the cleartext password with the hashed one
    this.password = hashedPassword;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});
```

This middleware is literally out of ChatGPT, but was essentially exactly the same as what I had before, with the exception of using hashSync and not hash (plus async/await).

Here is my findOneAndUpdate call:

```
const user = await User.updateOne(
        { _id: conf.user_id },
        { password: newPwd },
        { new: true, upsert: false, runValidators: true }
      );
```

The `runValidators: true` is what I learned here I should add, and adding it didn't affect anything. I've also tried having a second pre middleware specifically targeting `findOneAndUpdate`, with no success.

I ran some tests with a console.log in the .pre function, and confirmed that on new Users that console.log is accessed...but on findOneAndUpdate it is not. So the hook is being bypassed entirely, not simply failing to work.

Is there something in this that I'm missing using this solution?

Comment: An update: I found that perhaps my problem was that I wasn't using `$set` in my `findOneAndUpdate` call. I tried that to no avail:
```
const user = await User.updateOne(
        { _id: conf.user_id },
        { $set: { password: newPwd } },
        { new: true, upsert: false, runValidators: true }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

As is sometimes the case, the act of posting the question means I'd find the answer five minutes later. Part 1 was an error: I wasn't using `findOneAndUpdate` but had a brain cramp and used `updateOne`. I also learned that `.isModified()` is not a function in that hook any more. I learned the answer was this:

```
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate();

  if (update.$set && update.$set.password) {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(update.$set.password, saltRounds);

    update.$set.password = hashedPassword;
  }

  next();
});
```

So I did have to use the `$set` method, and then reference that inside the hook.